# Country domains, One.com and google

Tags: multiple-domains

Hi I have multiple country domains for one company and one top level .com domain. I am looking to consolidate these by have www.mydomain.com/us /uk /fr etc and point the country domains to each section but don't want to loose Google rankings. I also have add word accounts on each country domain. I want to know what is the BEST way to structure all of this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

301 redirect on every country domain, to corresponding pages.

Comment: Ok - So would i run the Google addwords on the counrty domains or the /country ?

Answer (score 0):

Use mod rewrite .htaccess
This should preserve your Google Page Ranks of your webpages. 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html